# How to reference a part of a 3D array?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, reference, max

So say I have a 3D array and I push values like so:

```
    @h = [[[]]]
    @h.push(["cat", "mammal", 100.0])
    @h.push(["lizard", "reptile", 300.0])
    @h.push(["dog", "mammal", 200.0])
```

How would I reference the max index by the 3rd element (the float) and then reference each individual elements of the index to output in this example just the value "reptile"?

I've tried:

```
@h.each do |(x,y,z)|
    if ( [x,y,z] == @h.max_by{|(x,y,z)| z} )
       puts y
    end
end
```

But it doesn't give me only the "y" value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@h = []   # not [[[]]]
@h.push(["cat", "mammal", 100.0])
@h.push(["lizard", "reptile", 300.0])
@h.push(["dog", "mammal", 200.0])
max_ar = @h.max_by{|ar| ar[2]}
p max_ar[1] #=> "reptile"

# Your way is less usual. It works fine, but you're working too hard:

max_ar = @h.max_by{|(x,y,z)| z} 
p max_ar[1]  #=> "reptile"
```

Comment: main pain area, you have removed - i.e `[[[]]]`.